# Concat string in php using javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How do I concat a string in javascript alertbox. 
The first part in the alert box is a simple text. whereas second part is a string retrive from mysql table.

```
$myname=$row["name"];
        echo '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction()
            {
            alert("Your name is: $myname ");
            }
        </script>
        ';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using single-quotes in your `echo` statement. Variables in PHP do not interpolate when used inside single-quotes. As Jeffman pointed out, you could use double-quotes, but I think using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) would be a little bit more cleaner:

```
echo sprintf('
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction()
    {
    alert("Your name is: %s");
    }
</script>', $myname);
```